# Using facebook sdk php 3.0 without json installed?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am trying some facebook php sdk 3.0 tutorial but i get the error:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I guess it has to do with my php version 5.1.6 on live server ( on my xampp i have 5.3.1). Now normally i use jsonwrapper but it doesn't seem to work as i still get the

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/fb/base_facebook.php on line 560

Is there another way to get this working??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has nothing to do with JSON.

You're doing `$object['element']` when you should be doing `$object->element`, or you can turn `$object` into an array by casting it `$object = (array)$object;`.